# Python requests connect to blocked server

Tags: python, python-3.x, vpn

I want to connect to one URL, which is blocked, using python [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

I used many different proxy servers none worked for me.  https://free-proxy-list.net/

```
import requests

x = '46.21.153.16:3128'
http_proxy  = "http://"+x
https_proxy = "https://"+x

proxyDict = {
  "http": http_proxy,
  "https": https_proxy
}


a = requests.get('https://example.com', proxies=proxyDict)
print(a.status_code)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "t.py", line 14, in 
> a = requests.get('https://my-url', proxies=proxyDict)   File "/home/user/Documents/backend1/venv-livedx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py",
> line 75, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/Documents/livedx/backend1/venv-livedx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py",
> line 60, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/Documents/backend1/venv-livedx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 533, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/user/Documents/backend1/venv-livedx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 646, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/Documents/backend1/venv-livedx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 510, in send
> raise ProxyError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-url',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /management (Caused by
> ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection
> failed: 403 Forbidden',)))

Comment: Can browse that url using your browser?

Comment: yes using VPN we can browse the URL

Comment: Try my solution below, and make sure your vpn is connected globally not just in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popular network firewall block popular user-agent considering them as bots.

Copy your browser agent and simply try changing the user agent on request. I bet request uses its own default user agent or the python urllib one.

Example:

```
a = requests.get('https://example.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36'})
```

Comment: how to get user-agent ?

Comment: Google is your friend, my fellow programmer. https://www.google.com/search?q=my+user+agent

Comment: whats the error? dont use the proxy now, you are already on vpn

Comment: dont use the proxy now, you are already on vpn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228611/discussion-between-c-grey-and-debendra).

Answer (score 1):

Try using *only* the http proxy for the connection.
So try changing your code to:

```
http_proxy  = "http://46.21.153.16:3128"
proxyDict = {
  "http": http_proxy,
  "https": http_proxy
}
```

The free proxy might not support ssl/tls connection.

Also, since you are using a free proxy make sure it hasn't expired.

Moreover if the url you try to parse has self signed certificates python requests might also fail, so you have to make the request using setting the verify argument to False.

`a = requests.get('https://example.com', proxies=proxyDict, verify=False)`.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?
Your proxy has expired by now and i tested using an SSL Proxy from [here](https://www.sslproxies.org).
Your code with an HTTPS proxy works fine. If i change to a non-ssl proxy it doesn't work. So i assume the proxy type matters.